# I've installed geopy but it says ImportError: No module named geopy

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror, geopy

I've installed geopy with

```
pip install geopy
```

I've checked on my command line, and it's there.

BUT whenever I try to use it, either in Anaconda, PyCharm or Jupiter Notebooks, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named geopy
```

I've had similar problems in the past with other libraries. I've used PyCharm and Anaconda at different times, and I'm sure that I have more than one Python version running on my computer. I don't know if this might be the reason this is happening.

Comment: check that you installed it in the conda environment you're actually using

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! I was indeed running the code on a different environment than the one I had installed the package in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some specific environment with conda, make sure you activate the environment

`>> source activate Envname`

and then after the environment is active then install the package

`>> pip install geopy`

I guess you are not

1. Installing the geopy inside the environment, and then trying to access the package after activating the environment **OR**
2. Installed inside the environment but not activating the environment and trying to access the package.

Comment: @Spartakus Please mark this as answered and approved if useful